# How can I style the text which user adds in a text input?

Tags: html, css

`<input type="text">`

For example the text that user writes as his email in an input. Is there anyway at all?

Comment: you can style it like any other css element.

Answer (score 0):

this is a simple example :

```css
input[type=email]:focus {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<label for="email">Enter your email:</label>

<input type="email" id="email"
       pattern=".+@globex.com" size="30" required>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can style the content of the input box like any other HTML element:

```
input{
    color:teal;
    font: 20px Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Another thing you can add is the placeholder attribute like this:

```
<input type="text" class="mytext" placeholder='Thats some really nice placeholder!' />
```